# Xcode 10.1 cannot invoke 'copyBytes'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, byte

When using Xcode 10.1 I get this error:

> Cannot invoke 'copyBytes' with an argument list of type '(to: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer), from: ClosedRange)'

on this line of code:

```
_ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &humid) {characteristic.value!.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 6...7)}
```

But it builds and runs fine in Xcode 10.2. Problem is our build servers use Xcode 10.1, what are my options here?

here is code for context:

```
var humid: UInt16 = 0
                //_ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &humid) {characteristic.value!.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 6...7)}
                _ = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &humid, {
                    _ = data.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: $0, count: 1), from: 6..<7)
                })
                humid = humid / 100
                weatherReading.humidity = Double(humid)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copyBytes()` in Swift 4.2 takes a `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` argument. Example:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                error: Error?) {

    let data = characteristic.value!
    var humid: UInt16 = 0
    _ = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &humid, {
        _ = data.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: $0, count: 1),
                           from: 6..<8)
    })
}
```

Comment: I get ```Ambiguous reference to member 'copyBytes(to:from:)'```

Comment: @DisplayName: Did you  use a half-open range `6..<8` as I suggested?

Comment: ahhh, that would be correct, but why is it not a closed range?

Comment: @DisplayName: I don't know. Just use the half-open ranges.

Comment: This ends up giving me an answer that's way off to what it should be

Comment: @DisplayName: I am fairly sure that this code produces the same result as your posted code which “builds and runs fine in Xcode 10.2.” In any case, it would be constructive  to give a concrete example: What is the data that you receive, which value is extracted, and which value should it be.

Comment: my function in 10.2 would give 77.2 for temperature, but what you have in 10.1 would give 35.1 - the correct values are displayed on the actual bluetooth device so It can't be a calibration error

Comment: @DisplayName: I don't want to sound rude, but all that does not help.  `humid` is an integer, so it cannot be 77.2 or 35.1. And without knowing which bytes are sent in `characteristic.value` we can only guess.

Comment: my apologies, the units that come back have to be converted by doing some arbitrary algebra specified in the companies documentation, I do that by creating a new variable which is a double value

Comment: I'll post the the entire function in the the question

Comment: @DisplayName: I suggested `6..<8`, not `6..<7`